# fixing overlapping images in a c# windows forms

Tags: c#, console-application, picturebox

I'm kinda confused how can I make the professor sprite to not overlap with each other like the box that can be seen in the screenshot below, I tried to find other solutions but still can't seem to make it work, any help would be much appreciated thank you

```
        private void MakeProf()
    {
        PictureBox prof = new PictureBox();
        prof.Tag = "prof";
        prof.Image = Image.FromFile("pdown.png"); //picture of the prof facing down (pdown.png)
        prof.Left = randNum.Next(0, 1400); //how far the prof will spawn
        prof.Top = randNum.Next(0, 800);
        prof.Size = new Size(110, 110); //size of the prof
        prof.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        profList.Add(prof);
        this.Controls.Add(prof);
        player.BringToFront(); //overlaps the player
    }
```

The Game that shows the enemy characters overlapping at each other where they are supposed to be 5 enemies
[image: The Game that shows the enemy characters overlapping at each other where they are supposed to be 5 enemies]

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for using controls (`PictureBox` objects) for your sprites? It would be much easier (and faster) just to subscribe to the `Paint` event of the background `Form` or `Panel` and draw your sprites there. It would also solve the overlapping issue if you use `Graphics.DrawImage` from the paint event handler.

Comment: I'm kinda new to c# and our professor in college haven't introduced us how to use Graphics.DrawImage if possible, would you be able to guide me on how use it on my code?

Comment: Make sure the new pbox [Bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bounds?source=recommendations&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) does not [IntersectsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=net-7.0) another one of the listed pboxes. Change the `Location` when it does. Give it a try.

Comment: Overlapping controls will not be able to have transparency. And since your images can't be nested (which often solves this issue) the above advice to draw them may indeed be best. - Will you need a event model/user interaction, ie will he be able to grab them with a mouse or just move them with the keyboard or by code?